# Sort all lists within a list

Tags: python, list, sorting

If you have a list of lists such as:

`lst = [[8, 4], [10,2]]`

How do you sort it such that the lst is:

`lst = [[4, 8], [2,10]]`

I have tried:

`lst = [i.sort() for i in lst]`

and:

`lst = list(map(lambda x: x.sort(), lst))`

but these just return a list with None.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: `i.sort()` returns `None` and sorts the list in place. Use `sorted(i)` instead

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`i.sort()` sorts the list in-place and returns `None`. Instead, you use `sorted()`:

```
lst = [sorted(i) for i in lst]
```

Or a for loop:

```
for i in lst:
    i.sort()
```